# Method of images for Black-Scholes PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finance

[The paper.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/51ef/48e2779c01a2c79a504df11969e9e80c66a3.pdf)

Let $\mathcal{L} = \partial/\partial t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2 \partial^2/\partial x^2 + rx \partial/\partial x - r $ be the Black-Scholes operator.

In the paper he mentioned about the "method of image solution" (Sec. 2.2), which transforms the PDE
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}P &= 0 \\
P(t,B) &= 0, \; 0 \leq t < T \\
P(T,x) &= f(x), \; 0 \leq x < B
\end{align*}
to another PDE with extended boundary condition that has the same solution as above
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}P &= 0 \\
P(t,B) &= 0, \; 0 \leq t < T \\
P(T,x) &= f(x)1_{\{x < B\}} - \left(\dfrac{B}{x} \right)^{\frac{2r}{\sigma^2} - 1} f\left(\dfrac{B^2}{x} \right)1_{\{x > B\}}  , \; 0 \leq x < \infty
\end{align*}

He takes the reference from a paper that I have no access to, and I can't figure out why one can think of this transformation.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, since the PDEs are the same on $[0,T]\times[0,B]$. So extending to $x>B$ doesn't make sense to me, since you seem to only care about the domain $[0,T]\times[0,B]$.

Comment: I guess that the use of Mellin transform (Sec 2.3) would require your domain of such function to be $[0 ,\infty]$, so they did such transform.

Comment: And there was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Then you would have to check that $\mathcal{L}P = 0$ for $x>B$ as well, then the extension is valid. Or maybe $\mathcal{L}P = 0$ on $x<B$ only, in which case the "arbitrary" term for $P(T,x)$ is indeed arbitrary. I guess the main point of the article is that the term is cleverly chosen.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}P$ is indeed $0$ for all $x$ after checking some resources. Some books provide the solution of this PDE, seems like the solution of the first PDE is also a solution to the second one.

Comment: Well I don't think that the author solve the equation first and then derive the PDE on $[0, \infty]$; there might me some ways to derive this, which is the thing I want to know.